# Clojure infinite loop

Tags: clojure

What is the idiomatic way to create an infinite loop?

```
while(true){
   calc();
}
```

I want to call the calc function forever. Only one function is called over and over again.

EDIT:
One other thing I forgot to mention is that calc has side effects. It does some calculations and modifies a byte array.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`while` is in the core libraries.

```
(while true (calc))
```

This expands to a simple `recur`.

```
(defmacro while
  "Repeatedly executes body while test expression is true. Presumes
  some side-effect will cause test to become false/nil. Returns nil"
  [test & body]
  `(loop []
     (when ~test
       ~@body
       (recur))))
```

Comment: Seems like (while (calc) nil) would be more useful.

Answer (score 17):

Using the `while` macro that [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515103/clojure-infinite-loop/1515275#1515275) provides in his answer it is a simple task to write a `forever` macro that does nothing but drops the boolean test from `while`:

```
(defmacro forever [& body] 
  `(while true ~@body))

user=> (forever (print "hi "))                         
hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi ....
```

This is the fun part of any Lisp, you can make your own control structures and in return you avoid a lot of [boilerplate code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_(text)#Boilerplate_code).

Comment: With while around, it would be kind of pointless to write a forever macro that does the exact same thing. Unless you wanted clarification on the name, and in that case, maybe somebody should write a function synonym macro! :p

Comment: I don't agree. Do you consider `dosync` pointless? You could just as well write (sync nil ...).

Answer (score 13):

(loop []
    (calc)
    (recur))

Comment: This being the syntax for simple tail recursion which I could not immediately bring to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use `repeatedly` like:

```
(repeatedly calc)
```

Rather than an infinte loop, this returns an infinite sequence.  The lazy sequence will be a little slower than a tight loop but allows for some control of the loop as well.

Comment: this will produce a lazy sequence as you said, so the side effects might not be executed. so the answer should include 'doall'